# Closing indexreader

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I've a line in my Lucene code:

```
try
{
    searcher.GetIndexReader();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    if (searcher != null)
    {
        searcher.Close();
    }
}
```

In my finally clause, when I execute searcher.Close(), will it also execute searcher.GetIndexReader().Close behind the scenes?

Or do I need to explicitly call searcher.GetIndexReader().Close() method to close IndexReader??

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, it's tough to understand what is the type of **searcher** in your snippet and how it was constructed. But you **should not** close the the index reader with **searcher.GetIndexReader().Close()**. The **searcher.Close()** will close all resources associated with it and index reader as well **IF searcher IS NOT** IndexSearcher instance constructed with **IndexSearcher(IndexReader r)**. In that case you have to close index reader manually.

Comment: thanks for ur comments...am creating searcher like this:

searcher = new IndexSearcher(myIndexDir);so in this case, how shall i close index reader?

Comment: If you are creating searcher from directory, closing searcher is good enough. It will internally close the reader.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, code like this is always a bad idea:

```
try {
    // Do something
} catch(Exception ex) {
    throw ex;  // WRONG
}
```

You're just masking the source of the exception, and still throwing. Better just to delete those lines.

If you didn't create the `IndexReader` yourself, you don't need to close it yourself. Chances are high that you don't need to use the method `getIndexReader` at all.

Also, unless you're assigning to `searcher` within the `try` block, there's no need to check if it's null, since there's no way it could get a null value.

Here's an example of what your code should look like:

```
String myIndexDir = "/my/index/dir";

IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(myIndexDir);
try { 
    // Do something with the searcher
} finally { 
    searcher.close(); 
}
```